# How can I find top 3 documents that are sent in a date range?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I use MongoDB to store user messages. By using aggregation framework, I want to filter messages based on their date and find top 3 messages that have the highest reply count.

I have the following JSON structure for many users:

```
[
  {
    "u_name": "Erdem",
    "details": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "m_type": "text",
          "m_date": 1565208272.547057,
          "m_content": "Sentence",
          "m_replied": 0
        },
        {
          "m_date": 1565208362.439494,
          "m_content": "Another Sentence",
          "m_replied": 50
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "u_name": "Tolga",
    "details": {
      "messages": [
        {
          "m_type": "text",
          "m_date": 1565201272.547057,
          "m_content": "Sentence",
          "m_replied": 0
        },
        {
          "m_date": 1565208322.439494,
          "m_content": "Another Sentence",
          "m_replied": 14
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I tried the following aggregation to filter out messages that are in specified date range and find the top 3 messages having largest m_replied count.

```
db.collection.aggregation(
[                                                                        
  {'$unwind' : "$details.messages" },                                                             

  {'$match': {'$and': [{'details.messages.m_date':{'$gte': 1564949580}},                          
                {'details.messages.m_date':{'$lte': 1664949580}}]}},                                                                                        
  {'$group': {'_id': '$u_name','s_msg': {'$max': '$details.messages.m_replied'}}},  

  {'$project': {'_id': 0,'u_name': '$_id','s_msg': 1}},                   

  {'$sort': {'s_msg': -1}},                           

  {'$limit': 3}                                                                                                                                                                                                   
]
)
```

However, this query doesn't return the messages having largest `m_replied`entries. Could anybody help me to find the right query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query can you the expected output:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$details.messages"
    },
    {
        $match:{
            "details.messages.m_date":{
                $gte:1564949580,
                $lte:1664949580
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            "details.messages.m_replied":-1
        }
    },
    {
        $limit:3
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Output:

```
{
    "u_name" : "Erdem",
    "details" : {
        "messages" : {
            "m_date" : 1565208362.439494,
            "m_content" : "Another Sentence",
            "m_replied" : 50
        }
    }
}
{
    "u_name" : "Tolga",
    "details" : {
        "messages" : {
            "m_date" : 1565208322.439494,
            "m_content" : "Another Sentence",
            "m_replied" : 14
        }
    }
}
{
    "u_name" : "Erdem",
    "details" : {
        "messages" : {
            "m_type" : "text",
            "m_date" : 1565208272.547057,
            "m_content" : "Sentence",
            "m_replied" : 0
        }
    }
}
```